# Importing libPusher in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, import, pusher

I am currently creating an app that makes use of Pusher in order to send packages from my app to the thing I am controlling. I ran into a problem with importing libPusher.h into my class.

I followed all of the instructions here--> http://pusher.com/docs/ios_quick_start
Yet I put in #import  at the very top of my file, I still get the error saying " 'libPusher/libPusher.h' file not found"
I can not find any libPusher.h file in the libPusher folder. Is there a problem with the files I downloaded for the library or am I doing something else wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just encountered this myself. I'm wondering if perhaps the Cocoapods version of Pusher is behind?

Anyway, a quick look at [Github](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher/pull/88/files#L0R11) shows that all that was contained in "libPusher/libPusher.h" was these four lines

```
#import <libPusher/PTPusher.h>
#import <libPusher/PTPusherChannel.h>
#import <libPusher/PTPusherEvent.h>
#import <libPusher/PTPusherAPI.h>
```

Including these where you would normally throw "`#import <libPusher/libPusher.h>`" should work the same.

Answer (score 3):

For me `#import <Pusher/Pusher.h>` works.

Comment: I've been using "libPusher/libPusher.h" but after updating some other Pods today (didn't update Pusher), libPusher started throwing this error. Switching to <Pusher/Pusher.h> worked for me as well.